# How to create dynamic height for TableView cell textview using Swift?

Tags: swift

I am creating single `Tableview` custom `cell` row with top and bottom two textview. Here, bottom textview need to adjust `height` dynamically based on `textview` text length.

My Storyboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pM7P.png)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.tableView.rowHeight = 280.0
}

//Choose your custom row height
private func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return 280.0;
}

// number of rows in table view
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return self.animals.count
}

// create a cell for each table view row
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:MyCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! MyCustomCell
    cell.sourceTextView.text = “ABCD….”
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Create an outlet for the textView and use it’s frame to adjust the cell height. Not posting an answer because this has been answered several times across SO and even on YouTube tutorials. Here for example: https://youtu.be/TEMUOaamcDA

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
func adjustUITextViewHeight(arg : UITextView)
{
arg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
arg.sizeToFit()
arg.scrollEnabled = false
}
```

In Swift 4 the syntax of `arg.scrollEnabled = false` has changed to

```
arg.isScrollEnabled = false.
```